# Is there an R function for getting the values that are on the brackets in a JSON file?

Tags: r, json

I'm trying to get some data in a JSON file using R, but it does not work when the data is under brackets and keys, I'm getting a lot of data, the problem is actually getting the value of the "released" parameter. example:

```
{
"index": [
    {
      "id": "a979eb2b85d6c13086b29a21bdc421b2673379a4",
      "date": "2019-03-22T01:20:01-0300",
      "status": "OK",
      "sensor": [
        {
          "id": "15",
          "number": 127,
          "callback": { 
            "released": true #it is not possible to return this data
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "db2890f501a3a49ed74aeb065168e057c3fd51d2",
      "date": "2019-03-25T01:20:01-0300",
      "status": "NOK",
      "sensor": [
        {
          "id": "15",
          "number": 149,
          "callback": {
            "released": false #it is not possible to return this data
          }
        }
      ]
    }
    ]
  }
```

Follow the code:

```
library(jsonlite) 
data <- fromJSON("Desktop/json/file.json")

pagination <- list()
for(i in 0:10){  
  pagination[[i+1]] <- data$index$sensor$callback
}

data_org <- rbind_pages(pagination)
nrow(data_org)
length <- nrow(data_org)
data_org[1:length, c("released")]
```

The response was being:

```
nrow(data_org)
# [1] 0
data_org[1:length, c("released")]
# NULL
```

Comment: Did you mean to use `data$index$sensor$callback` in every loop? That would be the same each time. nothing changes. And the `index` element contains an array, not a named list. So you'd need something like `data$index[[1]]$sensor[[1]]$callback`. You use `[[]]` with a number in R when the JSON data uses an array `[]`, and you can use `$` (or `[[]]` with a string)  when the JSON data uses an object `{}`.

Comment: Hi, @MrFlick Thank U so much, it works now :)